# Create a variable in the scope of a databind

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm databinding a Repeater and I would like to have access to a variable in the design code templates. The variable will contain some information for later use in the databinding action.
Ideally, the scope of the variable would be limited to the "databinding action". I could simply use a global variable, but hey, that would be cheating!

I tried using a script block to define the variable, but that doesn't work; the variable is created outside of the scope of the Repeater's templates.

```
<% bool x; %>
<asp:Repeater ID="suggestionRepeater" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <%# x = false %>  // x does not exist in current context
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


<asp:Repeater ID="suggestionRepeater" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <% bool x; %>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <%# x = false %>  // x does not exist in current context
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

So is this possible without taking the easy route and using a global (or protected) variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't. Not in the markup anyway. You can use a hiddenfield as another answer said *(Update: The other guy removed it later!)* and I usually when doing such set it visible false and viewstate false but hey, why the need for it at all...

You could do all sorts of fun in data binding events but this won't be much different as global variable.

But hey again, maybe you are trying to solve the wrong problem! Remember, this is .NET, not C++. Even if the variable is out of scope it'll be garbage collected only when needed. Even for a value type object, how big can it get?
Also, how much longer is the entire page life cycle compared to the repeater?

If the object is really "that" expensive and you "really" know in numbers a good reason you don't want it to life longer than the databinding, then it should also be disposable object (to guarantee proper clean-up of resource), and then I might do something like:

```
protected MyObjectType MyObject;

protected void BindRepeater(IEnumerable someDataSource)
{
    using(MyObject = SomeClass.SomeMethodToGetObject())
    {
        myRepeater.DataSource = someDataSource;
        myRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here the `using` should guarantee the cleanup via calling `Dispose()` implicitly. Of course it's still dirty as someone can make a mistake and use `MyObject` in another place when it's disposed or not assigned even if I put comments and everything, and it IS a global variable after all - Yes, it is cheating, or working-around limitation.

Again, I'm not suggesting you do the code above. I just show it's possible if you really know in numbers why you want to do that (otherwise, it's called premature optimization, you might end up with same performance or even slightly less performance when trying to solve the problem, or at best get very insignificant performance increase). What I recommend here is to look at the problem again and make sure you really need this.

Another approach to working around this also is quite the opposite to minimizing lifetime, it is increasing lifetime actually, like putting the object in cache or somewe are talking about.thing so that you don't have to create it more than needed or store many identical big copies, but this of course depends on what kind of data

Comment: Great, thorough answer. :)
Your solution is overkill for my particular situation, though. (The variable I need is really just a boolean, like in the sample code.)

Comment: That's exactly why I said I do not tell you to do it :) - Really, a boolean, that's much less than too little to worry about its lifetime. Just use a variable in the page and forget it. If the value is static or whatever and you don't want to have to compile or add to appSettings, use HiddenField.

Comment: If your concern is: Can it be done in markup? I guess the answer is no.

Comment: I'm not at all concerned about its lifetime, I simply don't want to pollute the global scope with a silly boolean used only in a very specific section of the page.

Comment: If this case ha[[ens a lot within the same page, it might be time to starts using (more?) user controls (and the boolean would live in one user control happily with its own Repeater, and any other stuff might be requried for them). If it's just this one odd case, then, still, it should be OK as a workaround for a platform shortage in current version.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, how about using a function and calling it in the script block?

```
<%# SetMyBool(Eval("RowID")) %>
```

And define the bool in that function? or return a boolean if you like?

Comment: But then the variable would go out of scope after the function returns. I would like to access the variable later on during the databind.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="VB" runat="Server"> 
        Dim rez As String
        public Function SetMyBool(v as string) As String
        rez=v
        End Function
</script>




<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="dsRateSet">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# SetMyBool(Eval("result")) %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<% =rez %>
```

Comment: Ideally answers will contain more than just code - please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Ideally code in answers use the same language as the question.